# fpdf: works great on localhost (xampp) but error 500 on server

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, fpdf

so this `fpdf` php library works great on xampp, fast and easy to customize if you need to create simple .pdf on the fly and based on form data.
My problem is, I pushed all updates on the server with git and now when I try to generate a .pdf I get a 500 error...without any further information.

The web application is built using CodeIgniter.

Will try to indetify the logs tomorrow, now I don't have access to the vps, in the meanwhile I was wondering if any of you have ever had this kind of issue before...

Comment: Something went wrong on the server itself so you need to check the server logs to find  out what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found an answer myself :D
it was an issue with the link to images, this solved:
`$this->Image( FCPATH . "assets/img/logo.png", 10, 6, 30);`